# Not able to access server when invoking gunicorn via .bash file

Tags: python, django, server, gunicorn

I am not able to access server when starting gunicorn via a .bash file I made. It works when I do it manually with this command

```
$ gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind 192.168.1.130:8000
```

Created a gunicorn.bash file from tutorials. I looks like this and runs without fault.

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="project"                                                   # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/username/projects/project                    # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/username/.venvs/project/run/gunicorn.sock     # We will communicate using this unix socket
USER=username                                              # the user to run as
GROUP=username                                             # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=1                                                   # how many worker processes shoul Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.production               # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=project.wsgi                                  # WSGI module name
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment

cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/username/.venvs/project/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exsist

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start yout Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use daemon)

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

I don't know how to troubleshoot this? Maybe some command to see what differs in running settings from manually starting gunicorn and from the .bash file?

Comment: Didn't I already give you the answer to this in your previous question?

Comment: Oh. Included my typo again. Fixed. No, it's running. But not able to access the website when using the .bash file. It works when I type the gunicorn command above. Since it's another issue, I thought it was better to make a new question instead of continue on the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind 192.168.1.130:8000
```

Above you use `--bind` with `host:port` but below:

```
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

you specify `unix:file` which will make your gunicorn listen on unix socket file instead of on your network interface:port, so just replace the `unix:$SOCKFILE` with `192.168.1.130:8000` and it should be accessible as expected

Additionally you can try and connect to the current config with a `curl` (`curl --unix-socket /path/to/socket http:/some/resurce`) or other tool of your choice to verify that it actually runs

Comment: Ok. I was following the tutorials and all mention this way. I searched for explaination of this. But can't seem to find anything that explains so I understand. Do I ignore best practise or expose server when changing from SOCKFILE to IP:PORT?

Comment: not really it still operates in the roughly the same way, exposing the server is up to your firewall rules so not much to do with where the gunicorn listens